# Leanback set controller visibility

Tags: android, video, leanback

I know that I can use `hideControlsOverlay(true);` to hide controller and the rows below but when dpad input it will be show up again. I want to change its visibility programmatically or not shows up when dpad pressed. I am using VideoSupportFragment[image: controller]

Answer (score 0):

Extend VideoPlayerGlue and override onCreatePrimaryActions() and onCreateSecondaryActions(), don't call super for these methods. Not calling the super for these methods will not add any primary and secondary action buttons.

```
public class MySupportFragment extends PlaybackSupportFragment {
  CustomPlaybackControlGlue myGlue = new CustomPlaybackControlGlue(requireActivity(), mPlayerAdapter, mPlaylistActionListener);
  ...
  myGlue.setHost(new PlaybackSupportFragmentGlueHost(this));
  ...
}

public class CustomPlaybackControlGlue extends VideoPlayerGlue {
    public CustomPlaybackControlGlue(Context context, LeanbackPlayerAdapter playerAdapter, OnActionClickedListener actionListener) {
        super(context, playerAdapter, actionListener);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreatePrimaryActions(ArrayObjectAdapter adapter) {
        //Do not add any secondary actions to the adapter
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreateSecondaryActions(ArrayObjectAdapter adapter) {
        //No need to add any other actions here. The Play/Pause action is enough.
    }
}
```